# Suggest me an android phone under 30k INR

Tags: android, mobile-phone

I'm using the same Xperia phone for the last six years, personally, I like Sony phones for their build quality, camera, UI, and reliability.
Basically, these are my requirements too.

Since Sony phones are not sold in India now, I am looking for a decent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

OnePlus Nord serie offer very good balance between options, quality and price.

For example [OnePlus Nord CE 2 5G](https://www.oneplus.in/oneplus-nord-2t-5g) offer 5G mobile network, 8GB RAM, 128GB storage, pretty good camera and (IMHO) one of the best UI you can find (in Android world).

Comment: How will be OnePlus reliability-wise?

Comment: @BrutalHaven, I have two of them (old models, 5T) and they are OK for more than 4 years